# Compiling Qt Creator with MinGW

Tags: windows, mingw, qt-creator

How does one recompile [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) using [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) in Windows XP?

Answer (score 3):

I would start by reading the [README](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/README), in it you will find:

> ### Compiling Qt Creator
>
> You need Qt 4.6 to build Qt Creator.
>
> We recommend that you build Qt Creator not in the source directory, but in a separate directory.
>
> To do that, use the following commands:
>
> mkdir $BUILD_DIRECTORY
>
> cd $BUILD_DIRECTORY
>
> qmake $SOURCE_DIRECTORY/qtcreator.pro
>
> make (or **mingw32-make** or nmake, depending on your platform)

Answer (score 0):

A Very simple way is to have in hand a pre-compile version of Qt Creator (even Previous Verion) and open the profile file.

If your development kit is set to minGW, that is you have ensure that:
- Qmake from the required version of Qt is identified in Qt identification
- Gcc path is set correctly)
then the existing version of Qt Creator will be used to do the build automatically.
Do not forgot eventually to do a off site build (enabling shadow build).

Regards